# Inserting Documents fail due to duplicate key generation(usecase: login and logout insert on browser refresh)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code logs a document on user connection and user disconnect. If the user refreshes the page, then the **disconnect** followed by **connect** happens quickly and the same objectid that is generated at the **disconnect** is generated at the **connect**.

```
function handleSocket(socket) {
socket.notify_user_state_data.state = "CONNECTED";
notify_user_state_collection.insert(
    socket.notify_user_state_data, function(err) {});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    socket.notify_user_state_data.state = 'DISCONNECTED';
    notify_user_state_collection.insert(
    socket.notify_user_state_data, function(err) {});   
}
```

This might be due to the warning mentioned in the documention http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

**The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation time is not strict within a single second**

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes it's true that the time portion of an ObjectId is granular only to the second, but there are also other parts that ensure that each generation is unique. See [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for a full explanation.  Not clear here how you are generating the data you are inserting. Perhaps more information or try debugging function results to see what that data is.

Comment: The data does not matter at all. Please look the edits. Removed all the unnecessary code.

Comment: If you are getting "duplicate key" errors then both the specific error and the data you are adding is most certainly the cause. Nothing is generating ObjectId's with the same value, so your assumption is not correct. Look at the data being passed in.

Comment: But the experiment shows otherwise. ie. The data is not used while generating the object id, perhaps since the objectid creation is done by the drivers(nodejs-driver), possibly it is a bug. Experiment result: Data about to get inserted. { username: 'a',
  state: 'DISCONNECTED',
  _id: 54f7ae85a0d77bc70f78b48a }. Already existing data in db { "_id" : ObjectId("54f7ae85a0d77bc70f78b48a"), "username" : "a", "state" : "BROWSE_PLAYERS" }. IN ANY CASE HOW TO HAVE MILLISECOND ACCURACY. ie. generate objectid as a function of millisecond and unix epoch.

Comment: So where are you generating that `_id` value? Is in in the document "before" it is sent to the server? That is essentially what I have been saying all along. It's not the fault of the ObjectId, but the fault of the data and generation. I suspect code is using the same generated Id. If you acutally read the link given you would realise that each successive call also adds a incremented counter so the time accuracy is not relevant here.

Comment: I do not generate any **_id** explictly. I am using nodejs-mongodb driver http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/contents.html. I guess the objectid is generated automatically by the driver.

Comment: In the collection docs http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection there is a pkFactory arg description says if this is not provided then some internal generation is done. So i guess may be i need to set this argument to generate a millisecond time. LIke Date.now().toString().

Comment: @NeilLunn Finally found the issue. The collections.insert(data_object), method adds an _id field to the **data_object** the first time. So when the second time the collections.insert(data_object) is called, it does not generate any value for the already existing **_id**. Please see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The collections.insert(data_object), method adds an _id field to the data_object the first time. So when the second time the collections.insert(data_object) is called, it does not generate any value for the already existing _id.

Taking the copy of the object to be inserted solves the problem as shown in the following answer.

```
function handleSocket(socket) {
socket.notify_user_state_data.state = "CONNECTED";
socket.notify_user_state_data = data;
var data_copy = {};
for (var i in data) {
    data_copy[i] = data[i];
}

notify_user_state_collection.insert(
    data_copy, function(err) {}); // after insert the data_copy will have a new _id property added to it.

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    socket.notify_user_state_data.state = 'DISCONNECTED';
    notify_user_state_collection.insert(
    socket.notify_user_state_data, function(err) {});   
}
```